# Make a:link only affect body in CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to make my css a:links only affect the body. When I add my CSS it affects all links including my menu and logo. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks

```
    a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FEF5DF 0%, #FEF5DF 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 0;
  background-position: 0 111%;
  transition: background-size .25s ease-in;
  padding: 2px 2px 0px 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #E2DDCA;
  transition: all 0.3s;
 
}

a:hover {
    background-size: 100% 88%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #f8cd5f;
    transition: background-size .25s ease-in;
}
```

Comment: what is a:link?

Comment: @l3est its what state the links are in. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

Comment: links in body? Aren't all elements in the body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything on your html page is contained within the body tag, so if you style your links, they're going to affect those links everywhere.

If you just want to style the links in a specific block, wrap that block in a div, give it a class, and then target a links within that class.

```
<body>
    <div class="my-content">
        <a href="#">My Link</a>
    </div>
    <div class="everything-else">
        <a href="#">My Link</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.my-content a:link { ...styles here...}

.my-content a:hover { ...styles here...}
```

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to work! Now for every page I just have to make the body have the same class. I wish there was just a way to umbrella everything in <body>.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to specific links you want to affect and then add the CSS to that class as follows:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="mylink">link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="mylink">link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="mylink">link 3</a>
```

And then your CSS would be as follows:

```
.mylink{
  /*your css*/
}
```